# Is there a way to prevent a new line when a text + a select input exceed flex container's width?

Tags: html, css

When I use a select form with a long text inside a flex container, the text goes to a new line, which is expected, but the select form also goes to a new line, even though there's plenty of room for it. However, this same select form won't go to a new line if the text isn't long enough to not break a line. What triggers this different behavior and how can I prevent it?

Here's an example:

```css
.entry {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: "Noto Sans";
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">This is a very long text that will definitely need 2 lines to be rendered. However, because of the select, it will take 3 lines even though it should take only 2
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select></div>
<div class="entry">Short text, 1 line. Why?
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: I'm doing some further tests and it's not related to the type of the html tag. It also works with a <span> for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is two elements. Text is full width so there is no more actual space. If you want select next to text, it must be in *one* element or without display *flex*.

```css
.entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 28px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <div>This is a very long text that will definitely need 2     lines to be rendered. However, because of the select, it     will take 3 lines even though it should take only 2
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="entry">Short text, 1 line. Why?
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Oh, so all that was needed was just to encapsulate it in another div?